# Increment & Repeat a range based on cell values in Google sheets USING FORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a range (B1:B7) containing Dates as listed below

1-Jan
1-Jan
1-Jan
2-Jan
2-Jan
2-Jan
3-Jan

I want this range to repeat N times based on a cell value and also increment each value of the range by 7 when the range repeats each time.

Eg : If the value in cell A1 = 3 , I want the date range to repeat 3 times starting from cell A2 and increment the values by 7 each time they repeat.

Expected Result :
1-Jan
1-Jan
1-Jan
2-Jan
2-Jan
2-Jan
3-Jan
8-Jan
8-Jan
8-Jan
9-Jan
9-Jan
9-Jan
10-Jan
15-Jan
15-Jan
15-Jan
16-Jan
16-Jan
16-Jan
17-Jan

Below is the formula I am using to repeat the range. But I couldn't find a way to increment the values by 7 when the range repeats each time.

=query(flatten(transpose(ARRAYFORMULA(split(rept(B1:B7&" ",A1)," ")))),"where Col1 is not null")

Result :
1-Jan
1-Jan
1-Jan
2-Jan
2-Jan
2-Jan
3-Jan
1-Jan
1-Jan
1-Jan
2-Jan
2-Jan
2-Jan
3-Jan
1-Jan
1-Jan
1-Jan
2-Jan
2-Jan
2-Jan
3-Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the exact ranges and specs in your post, this formula should work for you in A2:

`=ArrayFormula(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")+SEQUENCE(1,A1,0,7))))`

`FILTER` creates a virtual array of only non-null rows from B1:B.

To those dates will be added a `SEQUENCE` of numbers 1 row by [number in A1] columns, starting with 0 and skipping by 7. In the posted example where A1 = 3, then, this `SEQUENCE` would be as follows: `0  7  14` (each in a separate virtual column).

Those numbers will be added to every date in the `FILTER` to form a grid with as many rows as dates and as many columns as the number in A1.

This grid is `TRANSPOSE`d before the next step, to keep the dates in the order of your original vertical listing instead of deferring to the horizontal additions to each.

The grid is then `FLATTEN`ed into one column.

The formula is wrapped in `ArrayFormula( )` because it is processing arrays rather than single cells.

Keep in mind that you may need to format the results range (i.e., A2:A) in the date format of your choice. Otherwise, you may see raw dates, which will be numbers in the 44000-45000 range.

Comment: Thanks a lot Erik. Your formula worked like a charm. You have helped me to relieve off my stress which I had for the past 3 days trying to figure it out. Wish you abundance of  happiness.

Comment: Glad to help set your mind at ease. Thank you for your kind wishes.